# Creating \newcommand from existing command

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, nomenclature

So I have been using the `nomencl` package with the following `\newcommand`, to save having to type the abbreviation and then the `\nomenclature` command:

```
\newcommand*{\nom}[2]{#1\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}  %shortcut to \nom & leave abbv in place
```

I'd like to duplicate this functionality while using the optional argument for \nomenclature - `\nomenclature[]{}{}` So typing `(\nom[g]{N}{nematic})` would give (n) in the text and an entry in the nomenclature list...

I tried this:

```
\newcommand*{\nom}[3]{#2\nomenclature[#1]{#2}{#3}}
```

Which doesn't work, I don't fully understand how I should be doing this and I have obviously done something wrong. Would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without an MWE, but the way you are proposing to redefine `\nom` as `\newcommand*{\nom}[3]{#2\nomenclature[#1]{#2}{#3}}` makes all the arguments mandatory as in `\nom{A}{B}{C}`.  Is that the syntax you wanted?

Comment: The title of the question is misleading: a `\newcommand from existing command` implies `redefinition` or `construction a command sequence (name) from an existing command (name)` rather

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really sure of the terminology for what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\nom}{somm}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
    (#3)%
  }%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \nomenclature[#2]{#3}{#4}%
  }{%
    \nomenclature{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}
```

This defines `\nom` with the optional argument `#2` (for the prefix) and the two mandatory arguments `#3` and `#4`. If `\nom*` is used, the expliciting printing of `(#3)` is disabled.

The `\IfValueTF{#2}` checks whether `[]` has been used at all or not (True/False)`, the same is true of`\IfBooleanTF{#1}` which checks for the starred version (s).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\nom}{somm}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
    (#3)%
  }%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \nomenclature[#2]{#3}{#4}%
  }{%
    \nomenclature{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}
\makenomenclature


\begin{document}


\nom[g]{N}{nematic}

\nom*{F}{oomatic}

\nom{T}{eX}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dave: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\newcommand*{\nom}[3][]{#2\nomenclature[#1]{#2}{#3}}
```

Comment: This should work, but would enter an empty 'prefix' in the sorting, if `\nom[]{foo}{bar}` is used. (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call differently if the optional argument is missing, so the handier way is with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

[...]

\NewDocumentCommand{\nom}{ o m m }{%
  #2% the text to print
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\nomenclature{#2}{#3}}% no optional argument
    {\nomenclature[#1]{#2}{#3}}% with optional argument
}
```

The legacy definition (without `xparse`) might be

```
\newcommand{\nom}[3][]{% default value of opt arg is empty
  #2% the text to print
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \nomenclature{#2}{#3}% no optional argument
  \else
    \nomenclature[#1]{#2}{#3}% with optional argument
  \fi
}
```